# ContentFlow : How to tap and scroll, and flip Image when tap

Tags: javascript, css

I'm testing ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) and I'm trying to achieve both on the browser for desktop and mobile devices.

By default, desktop version works fine, when mouse click and drag. It scrolls and slows down and finally stop at an image. However, when I open up with iPad2, tap and drag, it jumps back like a rubber band to the initial image. Anyway to fix this behavior?

Also, I'd like to choose the image and click/tap to flip it over to another image. Is it possible?

I've searched and found Card Flip but I cannot incorporate to ContentFlow js/codes.

Appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Added:

I've tried to add to contentflow.js :

```
onclickActiveItem: function (item) {
var angle = 0;
angle += 180;
this.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + angle + "deg)";
this.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(" + angle + "deg)";},
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use contentflow.js, version 1.0.2, on an iPad mini by changing

```
this.iPhone = /iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

to

```
this.iPhone = /iPhone|iPod|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

(on line 14).

The problem i'm having now is that the end of a touch&drag movement is interpreted as a click; but I guess if your items aren't clickable, this won't affect you.